# What are some great books I can read to get prepared for Harvard's Math 55 this fall?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, analysis, soft-question

I am planning on taking Math 55 at Harvard this fall. I have a pretty strong background in multivariable calculus, and I would like to do some reading this summer to get prepared. I've heard that Analysis and Group Theory are good starting points. Does anyone know of some great books that would help me?

Comment: Stein and Shakarchi "Real Analysis" or, at least, Rudin. If this feels too hard, you are taking a wrong class.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_55

Comment: @MoisheCohen Going off of this link, it appears that the course covers algebra, not analysis: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M55a.16/h1.pdf

Comment: Caleeb, what is your familiarity with writing your own proofs?

Comment: @StellaBiderman the highest level math class available to me in high school was multivariable calc, so I have very little experience with writing proofs.

Comment: @StellaBiderman There's an "a" and a "b" part according to the Wikipedia page.  The "a" part is algebra, the "b" part is real and complex analysis. The notes you link to are the "a" part.

Answer (score 5):

**Practice reading and writing proofs.** This is so important that the topic of the proofs is secondary. As an undergraduate at the University of Chicago, I never took a mathematics course that wasn't proof-based, and our Math 55 equivalent assigned proofs to write for homework on day one.

I would recommend checking out *How to Prove It: A Structured Approach*, *How to Solve It: a New Aspect of Mathematical Method* and [Mathematical Reasoning: Writing and Proof](http://scholarworks.gvsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1007&context=books) as potential references. However, **at the end of the day the only way to become a proficient proof writer is to read and write them.**

Elementary number theory, discrete mathematics, and some calculus proofs will probably be the most accessible to you, so I would start there. I usually recommend Spivak's Calculus as a proof-based calculus book. You can find example proofs and problems for you to prove in any college level textbook, because college-level mathematics (especially at a university like Harvard) is almost exclusively about writing proofs. This website is full of proofs to read and questions that you can try your hand at proving.